# Infinite calls in axios.get

Tags: reactjs, axios

Following some tutorial, I made a todo app and is now working on connecting it to the database.
But doing so, while making an `axios.get` request its been called indefinitely.

My code

```
import React from "react"
import Header from "./Header"   
import Footer from "./Footer"
import Note from "./Note"
import CreateArea from "./CreateArea"
import axios from "axios"

function App(){
    const [notes, setNotes] = React.useState([]);

    React.useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/user')
        .then(res=>{
            const entry = res.data;
            setNotes(()=>{
                return [...entry];
            })
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log("Error: "+err);
        })
    })



    function addNote(newNote){
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/user', newNote)
        .then(res=>{console.log(res.data)})
        .catch(err=>{console.log("Error: "+err)})
        setNotes((prevNotes)=>{
            return [...prevNotes, newNote];
        });
        console.log(newNote);
    }
    function deleteNote(id){
        setNotes(prevNotes =>{
            return prevNotes.filter((noteItem, index)=>{
                console.log(noteItem);
                return index !== id;
            });
        });
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <CreateArea onAdd={addNote} />

            {notes.map((noteItem, index)=>{
                return <Note key={index} id={index} title={noteItem.title} content={noteItem.content} onDelete={deleteNote} />
            })}

            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
export default App;
```

I looked around and landed on this thread [Axios.get() ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62338214/axios-get-reactjs).  Following this I added the `useEffect` but still infinite calls are being made.

Comment: Try adding an empty dependency array in the useeffect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The effect is run infinitely since you're not passing an array of dependencies as the second argument to the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) call. Pass an empty array if you only want to run the effect when the component mounts.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array (`[]`) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always works.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get('http://localhost:3001/user')
    .then((res) => {
      setNotes(res.data)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error: ' + err)
    })
}, []) // an empty array of dependencies
```

If you set up [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks), it would display a warning to add `setNotes` to the dependency array since the effect depends on it. It's totally fine to add it since the function's reference won't change on re-renders.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get('http://localhost:3001/user')
    .then((res) => {
      setNotes(res.data)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error: ' + err)
    })
}, [setNotes])
```

---

This is unrelated to the question but you shouldn't hardcode the API URL. Use environment variables. If you're using [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/), you can [add environment variables prefixed with `REACT_APP_` to `.env`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) or you can use [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) if you have a custom Webpack setup.

Comment: @prashantgarg The code in my answer has the required changes. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this by making changes to it?
Earlier I tried doing this without useEffect where I made a variable ```entry``` and stored the content of ```res.data```. By doing so I was able to get the value in the form of an array inside the ```.then``` but as soon as I move out of ```.then``` my ```entry``` variable was reset to ```undefined```

Comment: @prashantgarg Were you trying to access the variable outside the `then` block? That won't work since the call is asynchronous and the value is only available in the `then` block.

Comment: Here is what I was trying to do
```
    var entry;
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/user')
    .then(res=>{
        entry = res.data;
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log("Error: "+err);
    })
    console.log(entry)
```

Comment: @prashantgarg `axios.get` is asynchronous and `console.log(entry)` gets executed before the promise resolves. That's why `undefined` is logged. I would recommend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) answer to gain a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Doing so, the `useEffect` is called on every function call. You should patch the code by adding something which never change overtime.

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
    //
    },
    []  //this makes the effect to be called the very first time only
)
```